# SQL: Get top products with limit?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I can get the top products like this:

```
SELECT productid, count(*) as total
FROM sales
JOIN product USING (productid)
GROUP BY productid
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

However, I want to get the top 9 products where the 10th contains the sum of all the products not included in the top 10. Is this possible with single SQL statement (without using multiple calls, subqueries, `UNION` or `WITH`)?

I am using PostgreSQL (bonus points if it works in AWS Redshift).

EDIT: My ultimate question is can this be done by only scanning the table once (which means all the extra sorting twice - hence why you can't use multiple queries)?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a UNION at least.

Comment: Don't forget ORDER BY to make sure to get the top 9 counts, don't expect implicit result order to be the same in the future! (Just a tip, use UNION ALL instead of just UNION. (UNION without ALL means duplicate rows are removed, which is unnecessary in many cases, like this.)

Comment: @jarih: You're right, I just typed it off the top of my head, it's not a real query from my application.

Comment: I'm with @JamesBlond: a `UNION` can do it. I would probably use a subquery without a `LIMIT` and an outer query to aggregate the non-top-10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT TOP(10) productid, count(*)
FROM sales
JOIN product USING (productid)
GROUP BY productid
```

Comment: There is no `TOP` in Postgres (plus it would do exactly the same as the SQL in the question - which is not what Elliot wants)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this qualifies as "only scanning the table once" in your eyes:

```
select case 
         when row_number() over w < 10 then productid 
         else null
       end as id,
       case 
         when row_number() over w < 10 then count_per_product 
         else total_products
       end as cnt
from (       
  select productid,
         count(*) as count_per_product,
         total_products
  from (
    SELECT productid, 
           count(*) over () as total_products
    FROM sales
  ) t
  group by productid, total_products
  order by count_per_product desc
) t
window w as (order by count_per_product desc)
order by case when 1 is null then 2 else 0 end desc nulls last
limit 10;
```

(I left out the products table because you only use the `productid` column and therefore there is no reason to include the `products` table).

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/313d3/2